# jqGrid pass value to form editing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid field I settled as like:

```js
colModel: [
    ....,
    {name:'Enabled',index:'Enabled',width:45,editable:true,edittype:'checkbox',
        editoptions:{value:"1:0"},
        formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowdata) {
            if (cellvalue == 0) return "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close hidden-align' style='text-align: center'></span>"; 
            else return "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-check hidden-align' style='text-align: center'></span>";
        },align:'center',formatoptions:{disabled:false}},
],
```

The matter is since I put images in the cellvalue, how I can pass to the Form Editing the value so the checkbox can be in checked state when the cellvalue is true?

Thanks in advance to all! 
Cheers,
Luigi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowdata) {
    if (cellvalue == 0) {
        return "<span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-close\"></span>";
    } else {
        return "<span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-check\"></span>";
    }
},
edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: {value:
    "<span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-check\"></span>:<span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-close\"></span>"}
```

or better to use **no `editoptions: { value: ...`**, but use `formatter` having one from the following values inside: `false`, `0`, `no`, `off`, `undefined`. See [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.formedit.js#L607) of jqGrid code

```
if(tmp.search(/(false|0|no|off|undefined)/i)<0 && tmp!=="") {
    $("#"+nm,"#"+fmid)[$t.p.useProp ? 'prop': 'attr']("checked",true);
    $("#"+nm,"#"+fmid)[$t.p.useProp ? 'prop': 'attr']("defaultChecked",true); //ie
} else {
    $("#"+nm,"#"+fmid)[$t.p.useProp ? 'prop': 'attr']("checked", false);
    $("#"+nm,"#"+fmid)[$t.p.useProp ? 'prop': 'attr']("defaultChecked", false); //ie
}
```

for the explanation. For example the formatter

```
formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowdata) {
    if (cellvalue == 0) {
        return "<span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-close\">0</span>";
    } else {
        return "<span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-check\">1</span>";
    }
}
```

(without `editoptions: { value: ...`) should solve your problem.