# jqgrid form edit returns server error when wrapped in formatter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

[jqGrid pass value to form editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425834/jqgrid-pass-value-to-form-editing)

as a follow-up question to this... I have a grid with one cell as a checkbox and form editing. I was able to load value of cell using this solution, however on submit it is passing back everything inside formatter quotes and throwing a server error. How can I pass back just the value 1:0?

Line from grid...

```
 { name: 'NS', index: 'NS', width: 20, editable: true, hidden: false, edittype: 'checkbox', editrules: { edithidden: true, required: true }, formoptions: { rowpos: 11}, formatter: checkTrue }
```

Formatter used...

```
formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowdata) {
if (cellvalue == 0) {
    return "<span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-close\">0</span>";
} else {
    return "<span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-check\">1</span>";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [unformatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter#unformatting)

```
{ name: 'NS', index: 'NS', width: 20, editable: true, hidden: false, edittype: 'checkbox', editrules: { edithidden: true, required: true }, formoptions: { rowpos: 11}, formatter: checkTrue, unformat: unFormat }

function unFormat( cellvalue, options, cell){
    return $('span', cell).text();
}
```

An unformatter takes the following parameters:

```
cellvalue - the value to be unformatted.  
options - An object that contains the row id and column model  
cellobject - A JQuery cell object.
```

Comment: You should change `unformatter: unFormat` to `unformat: unFormat`.

Comment: abosolutely!  I should have looked harder in the documentation!!